# c9.io Error: You don't have permission to access that port

Tags: python, django, cloud9-ide

So i was doing a django tutorial this weekend using the Cloud9 IDE on their web app c9.io. All is good and dandy until i get to the piece of running the server `python manage.py runserver`
You would think that it would work fine but i keep on getting this stuff.

```
python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
February 22, 2014 - 23:42:03
Django version 1.5, using settings 'djangotut.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.


 Cloud9  Your application is running at https://djangotut-c9-diaz994.c9.io



 Cloud9  Error: you may be using the wrong PORT & HOST for your server app
         use './manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT' to run your Django application
**Error: You don't have permission to access that port.**
```

I do not know why it is not allowing me to run this. It seems like it starts the server and then it kills it. Have any of you had experience with this on the c9.io site? Thanks alot.

Comment: try `sudo python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Its on one of their virtual machines so I dont have super user access. @SlaterTyranus

Comment: Have you solved this? If so, please answer it yourself so it helps the community.

Comment: @Feasoron I have not im thinking of submitting a bug report for it. Are you having the same issue?

Comment: I was but figured it out you literally need to run 'manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT' and then it works. Those aren't variables at the end, they are literal commands, which threw me.

Answer (score 1):

They don't allow access to the standard ports that django wants to use, but they do provide the appropriate ports in the form of environment variables.  Use this instead:

```
python manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats right. First use

```
python manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT
```

to start the development server and than don't forget to add allowed hosts to your settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<your_project_name>.c9users.io']
```